# How do I make network service start first?

Tags: networking

It's potentially a strange question but based in a real world scenario.

I've just had a usb disk that was mounted automatically in fstab fail. The consequence of that failure (in addition to the disk not being accessible) was the network interface failing to start. For the headless system that I have that was extremely frustrating.

This was not the boot disk or anything other than a simple ntfs formatted usb disk that had a samba share mapped to its mount point.

The instant I commented out the fstab entry everything worked again.

Logically no linux system should ever fail to start the network based on a failed fstab entry but that is exactly what happened.

How can I force my 16.04 system to always start the network even if there is an fstab issue?

p.s. The errors have not been kept and I'm not plugging the failed disk back in and putting the fstab entry back in just to reproduce it. I've suffered enough as it is.

Comment: Before you spend much time trouble shooting this just a reminder that 16.04 reaches EOL on April 22 so you may want to think about upgrading to 18.04 or 20.04. EOL means no more support or updates. Also means questions here will be off topic.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is answerable with the information given.

Comment: I expect someone with the appropriate knowledge will be able to answer it easily. The question is beyond most users though and that's ok.